# How to exclude duplicate addresses for reporting in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of distributors for the company.

Each has postal mailing information such as `address1, address2, city, state, zip`. I'm doing a report for sales using MySQL and want to **exclude** the `duplicated addresses` from the report so it just produces a list of each location. I can't delete it from the database because they (who set this up) use it to have one row per contact for the same distributor.

How can I exclude the duplicated rows from a report?
(mysql pseudo-code)

```
Select address1,address2,city,state,zip from distributors_db
where address1 only exists once?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are the duplicates exact duplicates? Or do you also need to strip out duplicates with alternative spellings, etc, from your report?

Comment: Good question. The duplicates are mostly exact, other times the data entry person might have a typo or a few different characters such as 1234 N. Main St and 1234 N. Main for address1, but even in those cases the city, state and zip code would match exactly just not address1 and perhaps address2. You have a suggestion to handle alternative spellings?

Comment: Uh oh.  If your addressses are exact the `DISTINCT` keyword does the trick simply.  If they aren't exact the problem is trickier. You either need to fix your data (gag gag) or figure out a `normalize_address()` function that can somehow convert `1234 North Main Street` and `1234 N Main` to the same value. This is notoriously difficult.  The Yahoo and Google mapping APIs, as well as a US Postal Service API, offer address-normalization features.  You might use those.  But your problem went from an hour's work to a week's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) keyword in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT address1
     , address2
     , city
     , state
     , zip 
  FROM distributors_db
```

Comment: Just curious, it is possible to do a DISTINCT on address1, but not say, the phone_number field? In other words, can the Select be...
Select DISTINCT address1, phone_number from distributors_db;
so that it only does the DISTINCT on address1 and not the phone_number, it just displays the phone_number along with whatever is returned? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in fact that's what this query does. DISTINCT is limited to one column only (as far as I know).